# Why does putting .read() in my code cause it to not work?

Tags: python, file

my code is as follows:

```
input_seq = open("input.txt")
sequences = input_seq.read()
output = open("output.txt", "w")

for dna in input_seq:
    trimmed = dna[14:]
    length = len(trimmed)
    output.write(trimmed)
    print("processed sequence with length " + str(length))
```

My question is with regards to the second line "sequences = input_seq.read()". When I include it in my code, it fails to execute properly. When i remove it, the code functions perfectly.

Why does that .read() line cause the whole thing to not work properly.

The input is

```
ATTCGATTATAAGCTCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATC
ATTCGATTATAAGCACTGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATGCTATCGTCGT
ATTCGATTATAAGCATCGATCACGATCTATCGTACGTATGCATATCGATATCGATCGTAGTC
ATTCGATTATAAGCACTATCGATGATCTAGCTACGATCGTAGCTGTA
ATTCGATTATAAGCACTAGCTAGTCTCGATGCATGATCAGCTTAGCTGATGATGCTATGCA
```

The CORRECT output is

```
TCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATC
ACTGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATGCTATCGTCGT
ATCGATCACGATCTATCGTACGTATGCATATCGATATCGATCGTAGTC
ACTATCGATGATCTAGCTACGATCGTAGCTGTA
ACTAGCTAGTCTCGATGCATGATCAGCTTAGCTGATGATGCTATGCA
```

Basically the aim is to remove the first 14 characters that's common to all the lines in my input.txt file.

There is no error message when I execute it, but nothing actually happens. The output.txt file remains blank.

Comment: what do you mean "fails" ? Do you get error message or get wrong result - always put FULL error message in QUESTION. And example data, wrong result and expected result.

Comment: You may as well remove the entire line, since `sequences` is not used for anything.

Comment: when you use `read()` then you read all to variable `sequences` and later `input_seq` is at the end of file and there is nothing to read - maybe use `for dna in sequences:`

Comment: I understand that sequences.read() is redundant in this case. I usually add it in out of habit and this is the first time it's given me any trouble at all. PS: This is my first foray into python!

Comment: user29578: Get over it. In Python, it's often unnecessary to use the `read()` method. Use `for line in open_file:` to process each newline terminated line of character data from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `sequences = input_seq.read()` read all file content in variable and after this statement `input_seq` points to the end of file.
You could use any of this two options, but not both simultaneously.
First option

```
with open('input.txt') as inp_seq, open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for dna in input_seq:
        trimmed = dna[14:]
        output.write(trimmed)
        print("processed sequence with length " + str(len(trimmed)))
```

Second option - read all input file in variable first

```
with open('input.txt') as inp_seq:
    sequence = inp_seq.read()

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for dna in sequence:
        trimmed = dna[14:]
        output.write(trimmed)
        print("processed sequence with length " + str(len(trimmed)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `with open() as`, don't use `open()` to read or write a file in Python. You can search for other questions to read more about this.

I've modified your code a little bit and I tested it, the result is correct:

```
sequences = None
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    sequences = input_file.readlines()

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for dna in sequences:
        output_file.write(dna[14:])
        print("processed sequence with length ", len(dna[14:]))
```

Comment: That's all well and good, but doesn't answer the OP's question.